# Float an input field to the right in a customized horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I customized the top menu in my Wordpress installation by adding a text logo before (outside) menu and a search input field as a new menu item. I am trying 1) to display all of them as one line and 2) to float ONLY the search field to the right of the site content full width. I can do the first with an `display: inline-block;`, but not the second. To float the search field to the right I must not to use the `display: inline-block;`, but in this case I will have my elements displayed as two lines. How can I solve this?

My HTML code:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="site-logo">InfoPsi.md</div>
  <nav class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <div class="menu-meniul-de-sus-container">
      <ul id="top-menu" class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item">Despre</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Blog</li>
        <li class="menu-item">Contact</li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-search">
          <input type="search" class="search-field" value="" name="s">
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

My CSS code:

```
.site-logo,
.main-navigation {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-navigation li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.site-logo,
.main-navigation li {
  padding: 1em 1.25em;
}

.menu-item-search {
  float: right;
}
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/iuriemalai/932enqzj/1/

My live site: http://infopsi.md/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the `.main-navigation` doesn't stretch. This can easily be fixed using flexbox. Just set the `.wrap` div to `display: flex` and the `.main-navigation` to `flex: 1` (to make it stretch). You also need to set `.site-logo` to `margin: auto` or else the text wouldn't be placed in the middle. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/932enqzj/3/) is an updated fiddle.